# Is there any MSbuild task to check if a string contains another string (similar to string.contains)

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have this Msbuild code:

```
<Import Project="A.proj" Condition="$(BuildDefinition) =='Dist Staging to Dev' Or $(BuildDefinition) =='Dist Staging to Dev(Services Only)'"/>
```

But I was wondering if is there anything similar to check if an string contains some text to get something similar to:

```
<Import Project="A.proj" Condition="$(BuildDefinition) CONTAINS 'Dist Staging to Dev'"/>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**MSBuild4:** As Julien said, in MSBUILD 4 is possible to user Property Function.

**MSBuild 3.x:** In previous versions is possible if you use [Tigris MsBuild Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

You can use task **RegexMatch** and use a regular expression

Answer (score 112):

If you use MSBuild 4, you could use `Property function`

```
<Import Project="A.proj" 
        Condition="$(BuildDefinition.Contains('Dist Staging to Dev'))"/>
```

*([More info on Property function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions))*

Comment: Works, although the syntax seems somewhat counter-intuitive... in your example if the result of the condition were true then it might read condition="$(true)". If you used OR - condition="$(true) OR $(false)". So what does the $(...) do? Does it execute whatever's between the parenthesis or just write it out to the condition expression before execution?

Comment: @Jacques, read the linked doc. `$` is a special character, that indicates what follows references a property. In this case, `BuildDefinition`. It won't be in the final string. The string will be `"true"`. In your second example, it would be `true OR false`, which presumably becomes `"true"` after evaluation.

Comment: Is there any way to make `Contains()` case insensitive?

Answer (score -5):

MsBuild [Conditions reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) doesn't have anything about a possibility of a "contains" function. Looks like your first version is the only option.

Comment: As others have pointed out, MSBuild 4 doesn't add new syntax for Conditions but lets you use property functions instead (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/04/02/msbuild-property-functions.aspx).