# Checking if a Property 'Starts/Ends With' in a csproj

Tags: msbuild

I'm setting up some configurations in my csproj files that will target different framework versions. Ideally I want configurations of 'Debug - 3.5', 'Debug - 4.0', 'Release - 3.5' and 'Release - 4.0'.

In my csproj file I want to do something like the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '${Configuration}' ends with '3.5' ">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '${Configuration}' ends with '4.0' ">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup
... check for "starts with Debug" to define Optimize etc.
```

However, I don't know how to go about checking that `${Configuration}` starts/ends with a particular string. Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit**: Marked answer below for pointing me in the right direction, which lead me to go with:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('Debug'))">
    ... setup pdb, optimize etc.
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('3.5'))">
    ... set target framework to 3.5
</PropertyGroup>
... and so on for Release and 4.0 variations
```

Comment: Tagged this [msbuild] for you, a csproj file is just an msbuild file and the additional tag might get some msbuild expert attention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any MSbuild task to check if a string contains another string (similar to string.contains)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289538/is-there-any-msbuild-task-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-similar)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

An MSBuild property is just a .NET String and has [property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions#string-property-functions) available.

```
Condition="$(Configuration.EndsWith('3.5'))"
```

Should work

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that the "starts" one is `Condition="$(Configuration.StartsWith('blah'))" since this answer doesn't cover this.

Comment: Yes. For example, `<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.StartsWith('Debug'))">` will work.