# How do I get MSbuild to use only one of the "DefineConstants" for condition test?

Tags: compilation, msbuild, include, conditional-statements

I have Condtional Compilation Symbols in a C# project defined as "ABC;XYZ", and I can use the following in the project XML file for conditional include of project code files during MSBuild:

```
<Compile Include="SomeFile.cs" Condition="$(DefineConstants)'=='ABC;XYZ'"/>
```

But I need something like the following which does NOT work:

```
<Compile Include="SomeFile.cs" Condition="$(DefineConstants)'=='ABC'"/>
```

Is it possible to use just one of the defineconstants for condition test?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out... [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289538/is-there-any-msbuild-task-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-similar) helped.

Essentially you just have to look into the string to see if it contains whichever tag you want to base your condition on. In my case this was the code for it:

```
<Compile Include="SomeFile.cs" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('ABC'))" />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I could not figure out how to do this with the MS documentation. Once again, SO is here to save the day.

Comment: how to check for `!Contains` ?

Comment: @zafar `Condition="!$(DefineConstants.Contains('NET5_0_OR_GREATER'))"`. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022)