# How to specify a '|net35|net40|net45|'.Contains($(TargetFramework)) condition for an ItemGroup (*.csproj)?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a C# (SDK) project with multi targeting where I have to include a certain file only in some older framework versions and I can easily achieve it like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="('$(TargetFramework)'=='net35') Or ('$(TargetFramework)'=='net40') Or ('$(TargetFramework)'=='net45') Or ('$(TargetFramework)'=='net451') Or ('$(TargetFramework)'=='net452')">
  <!-- do something -->
</ItemGroup>
```

But that looks a bit clumsy and is not easy to read, so I tried to do it like this (and dozens of variations of it) but without any success:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'|net35|net40|net403|net45|net451|net452|'.Contains('|$(TargetFramework)|')">
  <!-- do something -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there a way of doing it with a string contains operation?

I checked posts like these: [Is there any MSbuild task to check if a string contains another string (similar to string.contains)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289538/is-there-any-msbuild-task-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-similar) but what they do there does not seem to work for me.

The version I am using is Visual Studio 2019 (16.9.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you cannot call instance string functions directly on string literals. [The MSBuild documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild-property-functions/#syntax) suggests it's only possible to call instance methods on properties.

By moving the values you currently have inlined into a custom property, you can then use this property's `Contains` method like this:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Frameworks>|net35|net40|net403|net45|net451|net452|</Frameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="$(Frameworks.Contains('|$(TargetFramework)|'))">
        <!-- do something -->
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I corrected the contains expression to include leading and trailing pipes.